# Building a list from the Catresian square of an array

Tags: java, lambda

The code generates a list containing all possible combinations of the items of an array. Every triplet of items contains two operands and the third item containing `"-0.0"` or `null`, depending on the result of the given `BiFunction` applied to the operands. The list then is printed out, with additions for better readabilty (`null`s are not printed, operation signs are inserted). The output looks like

```
 ...
 -0.0 *     -30.0 = 
 -0.0 *      -5.0 = 
 -0.0 *      -0.0 = 
 -0.0 *       0.0 = -0.0
 -0.0 *       6.0 = -0.0
 -0.0 *      40.0 = -0.0
 ...
```

There are tho methods intended to be used in a real project, they are marked with "(meant to be used in a real project)".
Regarding formatting, it's my deliberate choice to write `if`s with a single nested statement without curly braces -- I hate to read code written in a sparse manner, when I can see only 3 substantial lines of code on the screen, and I never write such a code.

I'd like to know:

1. if the provided code conforms to the best practices regarding style (naming conventions, formatting etc);
2. Is there a smarter, neater solution for the task;
3. Are the comments intelligible enough (among others, my English is a concern);
4. What is the "right" way to check if a double value is `-0` (marked with "???")

The code:

```
package forquadruple.streamsandlambdas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

/**
 * 20.12.01 14:49:05
 * Builds and tests a list with the Cartesian products of the given operands
 * that are String representations of double values.
 * The list should consist of triplets of Strings, where each triplet
 * includes a pair of string representations of two double operands, and the third item of the triplet
 * should depend on the result of the given {@code BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> function} applied to the operands.<br>
 * If the result of the function is -0, the third item of the triplet should contain "-0.0",
 * otherwise it should be {@code null},
 * in other words, for any n<pre>
 * triplet[n*3 + 2] =
 *    (function(triplet[n*3], triplet[n*3 + 1]) == -0 ? "-0.0" : null)
 * </pre>
 * for example, for multiplication the list may contain the following triplets:
 * <pre>
 * "0", "-5", "-0",
 * "5", "-5", null,
 * </pre>
 */
public class TestListGeneration {

  private static final char[] OP_SIGNS = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};

  private static final String[] OPERANDS = new String[] {
    "-Infinity",
    "-30.0",
    "-5.0",
    "-0.0",
    "0.0",
    "6.0",
    "40.0",
    "Infinity",
    "NaN",
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestListGeneration().testGeneration();
  }

  /**
   * Build some sample lists and print their contents 
   */
  private void testGeneration() {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    final int sectionSize = (OPERANDS.length * OPERANDS.length + 1) * 3;      // To know when to add a gap between different operations

  // add lists for different operatins
    list.addAll(cartesianSquareWithMinusZeros(OPERANDS, (a, b) -> a + b));   // add sums of operands
    list.add(""); list.add(""); list.add(""); // Just a gap between operations, for better readability

    list.addAll(cartesianSquareWithMinusZeros(OPERANDS, (a, b) -> a - b));
    list.add(""); list.add(""); list.add("");

    list.addAll(cartesianSquareWithMinusZeros(OPERANDS, (a, b) -> a * b));
    list.add(""); list.add(""); list.add("");

    list.addAll(cartesianSquareWithMinusZeros(OPERANDS, (a, b) -> a / b));
    list.add(""); list.add(""); list.add("");

    printTheList(list, sectionSize);
  }

  /**
   * (meant to be used in a real project)
   * Builds a list of all possible pairs of operands (their Cartesian square)
   * supplemented with "-0.0" (if the result of the given operation applied to the operands is -0)
   * or with null (in all other cases).
   * @param operands -- an array containing string representations of double operands
   * @param operatoin -- the operation whose result affects the third
   * @return the resulting list 
   */
  public List<String> cartesianSquareWithMinusZeros(String[] operands, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> operatoin) {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(OPERANDS).forEach(s1 -> {
      Arrays.stream(OPERANDS).forEach(s2 -> {
        result.add(s1);
        result.add(s2);
        result.add(isMinusZero(s1, s2, operatoin)? "-0.0" : null);
      });
    } );
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * (meant to be used in a real project)
   * Checks whether the given operation applied to the given operands results in -0
   * @param op1str -- 1st operand as a String
   * @param op2str -- 2nd operand as a String
   * @param operation -- the operation to perform on the operands
   * @return true, if the result of the operation is -0, false otherwise
   */
  private boolean isMinusZero(String op1str, String op2str, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> operation) {
    final double op1 = Double.parseDouble(op1str);
    final double op2 = Double.parseDouble(op2str);

    // ??? is there a neater way to check if a value is -0?  
    return Double.doubleToLongBits(operation.apply(op1, op2)) == 0x8000_0000_0000_0000L;
  }

  /**
   * Prints the list, just to watch the contents of the list
   * @param list
   * @param sectionSize
   */
  private void printTheList(final List<String> list, final int sectionSize) {
    String s = "";
    char opSign = '+';
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ) {

      if (i % sectionSize >= sectionSize - 3) // Just a gap between operations, for better readability
        opSign = ' ';                         // Will be an empty line
      else
        opSign = OP_SIGNS[i / sectionSize];   // Will be a line with the operands and (perhaps)

      say("%9s %s %9s %s %s",
          list.get(i++), opSign, list.get(i++),  // Operands separated by the operation sign
          opSign == ' ' ? ' ' : '=',             // and perhaps accompanied with the result
          (s = list.get(i++)) == null? "": s);   // replace nulls with empty strings
    }
  }

  /** print to console, just for convenience */
  public static void say()  { System.out.println(); }
  public static void say(Object o)  { System.out.println(o); }
  public static void say(String format, Object... args) { System.out.println(String.format(format, args)); }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's no reason to use `Arrays#stream` to iterate an array. It's slower and requires all captured locals to be final, as opposed to a simple `for (String s1 : OPERANDS)` which compiles directly to a normal for loop.
- 'Operation' is misspelled several times